# From SQL to LINQ

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework-4

I am trying to figure out how to translate this SQL select to LINQ, but I have not been able to figure it out yet.

I am getting the last test record for each Id(PersonId), for each test, for each month, per year. Basically, getting the last score of the month for each person per year.

```
CREATE TABLE #MyTable 
(
   Id INT,
   Score INT,
   TestName VARCHAR(50),
   TestDate DATETIME
)

INSERT INTO #MyTable

VALUES

(1, 10, 'Math', '2011-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 25, 'Math', '2011-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 100, 'Math', '2011-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 10, 'Reading', '2011-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 25, 'Reading', '2011-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 100, 'Reading', '2011-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 10, 'Math', '2011-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 25, 'Math', '2011-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 100, 'Math', '2011-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 10, 'Reading', '2011-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 25, 'Reading', '2011-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 100, 'Reading', '2011-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 10, 'Math', '2011-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 25, 'Math', '2012-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 100, 'Math', '2012-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 10, 'Reading', '2012-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 25, 'Reading', '2012-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(1, 100, 'Reading', '2012-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 10, 'Math', '2012-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 25, 'Math', '2012-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 100, 'Math', '2012-12-06 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 10, 'Reading', '2012-12-16 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 25, 'Reading', '2012-12-26 00:00:00.000')

,(2, 100, 'Reading', '2012-12-06 00:00:00.000')



SELECT DISTINCT
M.Id,M.Score,M.TestName, M.TestDate

FROM 
#MyTable M

WHERE
M.TestDate IN (
SELECT MAX(m.TestDate)
FROM #MyTable m
GROUP BY MONTH(TestDate), YEAR(TestDate)
)

DROP TABLE 
#MyTable
```

BEFORE SubQuery:

[image: before image]

FINAL RESULT after SubQuery used, Results 8 records returned:

[image: SQL image]

What I have:

```
  from a in MyTable
  where   a.TestDate == from b in MyTable
   group b.TestDate.Value.Month,
        a.TestDate.Value.Year
```

Comment: Why is your SQL query yielding duplicate entries when you are selecting distinct values?

Comment: They aren't yielding duplicates the year is different, and the subject as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var q1= 
    from entry in MyTable
    group entry by new{entry.TestDate.Month, entry.TestDate.Year} into g
    select g.Where(entry => entry.TestDate == g.Max(e => e.TestDate));
```

Note that this will literally create groups for each month/year combo, which may actually fit your business case better. If you need it flattened though, you can say:

```
var q2 = from g in q1
         from entry in g
         select entry;
```

or:

```
var q2 = q1.SelectMany(g => g)
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
from m in myTable
where myTable
    .GroupBy(x => new { x.TestDate.Month, x.TestDate.Year })
    .Select(grp => grp.Max(x => x.TestDate))
    .Any(x => x == m.TestDate)
select new { m.Id, m.TestScore, m.TestName, m.TestDate };
```